# Javascript filter return empty array

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4];

// iterate over elements and filter
var res = data.filter(function (v) {
  
    return data.filter(function (v1) {   
    });
});

console.log(res);
```

In this code i try to use double filter to see what will return to `var res`. **My expectation for `var res` is empty array** and the **second filter will also giving me a empty array**(which meet my expectation)

but in reality `var res` return [1,2,3,5,2,1,4], slap my face hard.

In my understanding `filter` return true or false, **if true will return array and element with the value  else will return nothing (empty array)**.Second `filter` does what i think (return 7 empty array).

So why 7 empty array return back to **first** `filter`,**first** `filter` is giving me all the element of the array? `[1,2,3,5,2,1,4]`.Because i am not returning true or false value to **first** `filter` instead **second** `filter` is returning 7 empty array to **first** `filter`.

Comment: *"In my understanding filter return true or false"* No, it returns an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ filter (which makes returning its result unsuitable for a `filter` callback, since any array is truthy, so all elements will be kept). I strongly recommend that when a function doesn't do what you expect, your first step in debugging should be to read the reference information for the function.

Comment: It's interesting that you're expecting an array from the outer `filter` and a boolean from the inner `filter`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now i get it array even it is empty is also return true value.Thank you

Comment: @Teemu oops now i see where my logic is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, because the array is an object, even if there is no value in the array, the if judgment will be converted to true.

eg.0

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4];
// iterate over elements and filter
var res = data.filter(function (v) {
  return false
});

console.log(res); // []
```

eg.1

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4];

// iterate over elements and filter
var res = data.filter(function (v) {

  return true
});

console.log(res);// [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
```

eg.2

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4];

// iterate over elements and filter
var res = data.filter(function (v) {

  return []
});

console.log(res);// [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvaHT.png)

Comment: super clear answer for me thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method works as the following according to the documentation :

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

In another words, the filter methods take a method that returns a boolean an apply it to each element of the array. If the method return `true`. The element will be returned in the new array returned by the function, otherwise it wont

Example if you want to get odd items :

```js
function isOdd(number){
  return number % 2 !== 0
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,5]

const arrayFiltered = array.filter(isOdd)
console.log(arrayFiltered)
```

You can also do it using [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]

const arrayFiltered = array.filter(number => number % 2 !== 0)
console.log(arrayFiltered)
```